# Import xml into a xml and read it with actionscript 3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, import

I want to import a xml into an xml and read it with ActionScript 3.
A single imported xml-File is possible to import but I have a big problem using it that way I want to.

So my first xml-File looks that way:

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ENTITY bonuses SYSTEM "bonuses.xml">
]>    
<mission>
            ...
            <wealth money="1000" />
            <bonuses>bonus</bonuses>
            <bonuses>
                <first>&bonuses;</first>
                <second>&bonuses;</second>
            </bonuses>
        </mission>
```

My Second file looks that way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bananas>
    <descr>Banana Description</descr>
    <impact>You gain more gold!</impact>
    <bonus>15</bonus>
</bananas>
```

I'm trying to access the xml file with this function:

```
private function xmlLoaded(e:Event):void 
{
    _xml = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace("XML LOADER: XML LOADED CORRECTLY");
// Correct Output: Bonus
        trace("XML LOADER: BONUS 0: " + _xml.mission[0].bonuses[0]); 
// Incorrect Output: Nothing!
    trace("XML LOADER: BONUS 1: " + _xml.mission[0].bonuses[1].first.descr);
    _stage.dispatchEvent(new Event("completed"));
}
```

Like I said this works fine for the first loaded xml file but not for the imported. Are there any soultions or is it a restriction of actionscript?

Thanks a lot!

Greetings
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are many bizarre things in your code.

1) Are you loading both XMLs into the same object `_xml`? You should have a different object for each XML. When you do the following code, you are removing what's inside `_xml` and putting something new.

```
_xml = new XML(e.target.data);
```

2) Of course your second trace will never work, even if you had 2 XML objects, because it's not using the nodes correctly... it should be simply this.

```
trace(_xml.descr);
```

If you need to combine the 2 XMLs into one XMl object, you need to do that **after** loading both XMLs.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use `XML`, use `JSON`. Actionscript 3 has a native `JSON` parser, which is faster than the default `XML` parser. `JSON` supports arrays, it's easier to read and 50% to 66% in size of the same data in `XML`. Actionscript 3 converts a `JSON` string into an `Object` with properties which eliminates the need of stuff like `_xml.mission[0].bonuses[1].first.descr`.

Once you switch to `JSON`, problems like yours just fly away on the back of butterflies *twinkle, twinkle*.

If you DO have to use an XML, then get yourself or make yourself an XML to Object converter, which is something you can easily debug. Convert attributes to properties, child nodes into an array with said children, etc.

Comment: That is something very arguable that will depend on many factors. For example editing complex JSON files by hand can be a real pain (if that is the case). Another factor is that in most cases performance and file size are negligible. Sure if you are consuming the data from a WS JSON will be easier to handle for the consumer, but that is not always the case. You like it better, fine, but don't preach it like it's the absolute truth. http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2007/11/28/introducing-e4x.html

Comment: Trying to bury rotting technology, that's all. Both are tree structure, its a pain to edit both of the complexity you describe. Both have validators existing. I agree e4x is useful, but apparently not in this case.